# Loop the Loop in non-inertial frame

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames

I encountered the following question, but could not solve it for several days now.

The question is what is the minimum initial velocity one should give mass $$m$$, in order for it to go through the loop of the cart:

[image]

The mass of the cart is $$km$$

Radius $$R$$

And all surfaces are frictionless.

I'm aware of the regular loop-the-loop questions, but here the cart will move in order to keep conservation of momentum.

The exercise states that you should solve this in the CM frame, but I still don't understand how to write the equation.

The center of mass is accelerating upwards and gains:

$$\Delta h = 2R(\frac{1}{{k + 1}})$$

But how can I get the right equation for the CM frame?

Comment: Try to write the coordinates of the center of mass as a function of the position of the mass on the loop, that might help making the change of frame.

Comment: Yes, I know how to do the change of frame, but what is the condition for the successful loop?

Comment: Give it a longer thought, this point is rather classical imo, you should have encountered it in simpler "Loop the loop" exercises

Comment: In usual Loop the loop questions, we are getting the condition from forces. Here though, the cart is accelerating and there are non-inertial forces - which means that the zero Normal point might not be at the top of the circle.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the particle moves smoothly round the circle both horizontal momentum and mechanical energy are conserved. When the particle reaches the top of the loop it has gained gravitational PE and the system (cart and particle) have lost some KE. You can use conservation laws to calculate the speed of the particle and the cart when the particle reaches the top of the loop.

The condition for Loop-the-Loop is that the centripetal acceleration of the particle at the top of the loop is equal to or greater than the acceleration due to gravity. If the cart were stationary the particle would be moving in a circle of radius $R$ at this point. However, the cart is moving sideways, so in the ground frame the circular path of the particle is flattened horizontally, and the radius of curvature of this path is smaller than $R$ at the top. This makes it difficult to use any frame in which the cart is moving - eg the centre of momentum frame or the ground frame.

It is probably easiest to use the frame in which the cart is stationary and the particle is moving in a circle of radius $R$. The velocity of the particle for use in calculating centripetal acceleration is that relative to the moving cart.

At the top and bottom of the loop the particle is moving sideways, so it is not necessary to consider the vertical motion of the COM. These are the only two instants you need to consider.

See related question and diagram in [Mass inside cavity in block free to move](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/373695).